# Difference between scriban import and add

Tags: sxa, scriban

we are currently building a foundation in Sitecore SXA to process the external data using scriban context. Since we are to new scriban world and tried to understand how scriban processors are adding runtime objects, but couldn't able to understand difference between import and add.

Most of the import functions are having delegate but add functions doesn't. In some of the scriban processor's both are used and added to runtime. for example, "sc_placeholder" context. Attached screenshot. Please help here to add more context

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/scriban/scriban/blob/master/doc/runtime.md  I would start with the official documentation.

Comment: I would say "Add" means something what is already ready (prepared data) and "Import" means something what you will get